# Sort data frame rows in the right columns

Tags: r

I am currently in the data cleaning process. My data has more than 6 digits rows. I cannot come up with a solution in order to have the data in the right order. Can you give me a hint please?

Thanks in advance

```
df <- data.frame(price= c("['380€']", "3hr 15 min", "4hr", "3hr 55min", "2h", "20€"),
           airlines = c("['Icelandir']", "€1,142", "16€", "17€", "19€", "Iberia"),
           duration = c("['3h']","Turkish airlines", "KLM", "easyJet", "2 hr 1min", "Finnair"),
           depart = c("LGW", "AMS", "NUE", "ZRH", "LHR", "VAR"))
```

My desired output is

```
price        airline           duration          price_right  airline_right    duration_right  depart
['380€']     ['Icelandair']    ['3h']             ['380€']    ['Icelandair']   ['3h']          LGW
3 hr 15 min  €1,142            Turkish airlines   €1,142      Turkish airlines 3 hr 15 min     AMS
4hr          €16                KLM               €16         KLM              4hr             NUE
3hr 55min    €17                easyJet           €17         easyJet          3hr 55min       ZRH
2h           €19                2hr 1min          €19         Iberia           2h              LHR
2hr min     "Iberia"            Finnair           €20         Finnair          2hr 1min        VAR
```

Comment: Your question is not reproducible and it is not clear. Please clarify!

Comment: `Error: unexpected '[' in "data.frame(price= c(["`

Comment: Hello @TarJae, thank you for your advice. I am trying to create a variable that orders the values of each column correctly.

Comment: Hello @dcsuka I fixed it right now :)!

Answer (score 1):

For this example we could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  group_by(group =as.integer(gl(n(),3,n()))) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(name = case_when(id == 1 ~ "price",
                        id == 2 ~ "duration",
                        id == 3 ~ "airlines",
                        TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group, -id) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-id)
```

```
 price    duration   airlines        
  <chr>    <chr>      <chr>           
1 ['380€'] ['3h']     ['Icelandir']   
2 €1,142   3hr 15 min Turkish airlines
```

Comment: your code works only with 2 row and 3 variables. I I expand the data to 100 rows the output is not the desirable. For example, the first 30 rows there are are 3 columns only with prices values, then the other 30 columns are full of airlines values and so on.  However I thank you for your help